# Remove 'Change' button from MaintenaceTypeDialog

Tags: wix, wix3.5

After installation of the setup, when the user again clicks on the setup to open it in the maintenance mode, I want that only the 'Repair' and 'Remove' options are shown and the 'Change' option is not shown.

I can disable the 'Change' button using  but I want to remove it and don't want to display it to the user.

Please suggest if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the Wix dialog set (.wxs) in your installer project (they can be downloaded from git). Edit `MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs` file and remove the repair button and label.

Comment: I got the MaintenanceTypeDlg code from http://nsclient.org/nscp/browser/branches/stable/helpers/installer/custom-ui/MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs. Can u please elaborate how can I replace this(after I have edited the code to remove 'Change' button) dialog with the custom MaintenanceTypeDlg.

Comment: I found the link for customizing WixUI_InstallDir at the link http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/. But this isn't clear to me how to do it for MaintenanceTypeDlg. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Piyush do you have all the Wix Dialog files (.wxs)? If yes jut add all the dialog files in your project. Refer the UI in your main .wxs file e.g. `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`. Open `MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs` and remove the pushbutton & label for repair

Comment: Hi Ajay, I have downloaded the MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs from the link http://nsclient.org/nscp/browser/branches/stable/helpers/installer/custom-ui/MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs After that I have added this file in my project and renamed it to MyMaintenancetypeDlg.wxs as explained in the link http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/ and removed the Change button. By doing this, still the default Maintenance screen comes up with the Change button. Sorry for my ignorance that I am not able to get you point..

Comment: @Piyush download all the files (.wxs) under http://nsclient.org/nscp/browser/branches/stable/helpers/installer. Remove the reference `WixUIExtension.dll` from your project. Modify `MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Windows Installer properties which start with ARPNO prefix: [ARPNOMODIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367590.aspx) (this is what you need), [ARPNOREPAIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367592.aspx) and [ARPNOREMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367591.aspx). These properties define the availability of option in Add/Remove Programs console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Yan, As already quoted by me that I can disable the 'Change' button, I want to remove it and don't want it to be displayed to the user.

Comment: Hi user514469, sorry I misunderstood your question. My answer refers to the case when you'd like to customize the view of your product in Add/Remove Programs. If you're talking about the Maintenance Dialog itself, then ajay_whiz's answer is probably what you should do. But keep in mind that your installer might run without UI at all, and in this case user will have the only option to start Maintenance Mode from Add/Remove Programs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **WixUI_Mode** and not using customized MaintenanceTypeDlg.wxs then you should define **`<Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />`** in YOUR_MAIN_UI.wxs file.